# Print data of one column of data gridview in print document in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

```
int height = 300;
int i = 0;

while (i < PurchaseDepartDataGridView.Rows.Count)
{
     height += PurchaseDepartDataGridView.Rows[0].Height;              
     e.Graphics.DrawString(PurchaseDepartDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(),PurchaseDepartDataGridView.Font,Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(25,height,PurchaseDepartDataGridView.Columns[0].Width,PurchaseDepartDataGridView.Rows[i].Height));
     i++;      
}
```

This code does not work properly.

I want only to print the values of only one column of datagridview.

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of _does not work properly_ exactly? You get error or exception? Unexpected result?